# Algorithm should I create a new thread?

Tags: python, math, multithreading

Is there an algorithm that checks whether creating a new thread pays off performance wise?
I'll set a maximum of threads that can be created anyway but if I add just one task it wouldn't be an advantage to start a new thread for that.
The programming language I use is python.

### Edit 1#

Can this question even be answered or is it to general because it depends on what the threads work on?

Comment: .... generic answer: profiling!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

python (at least standard CPython) is a special case, because it won't run more than one thread at a time, therefore if you are doing number-crunching on a multiple cores, then pure python isn't really the best choice.

In CPython, while running python code, only one thread is executing. It protected by the [Global Interpreter Lock](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock). If you're going IO or sleeping or waiting on the other hand, then python threads make sense.

If you are number-crunching then you probably want to do that in a C-extension anyway. Failing that the [multiprocessing library](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) provides a way for pure python code to take advantage of multiple cores.

In the general, non-python, case: the question can't be answered, because it depend on:

1. Will running tasks on a new thread be faster at all>
2. What is the cost of starting a new thread?
3. What sort of work do the tasks contain? (IO-bound, CPU-bound, network-bound, user-bound)
4. How efficient is the OS at scheduling threads?
5. How much shared data/locking do the tasks need?
6. What dependencies exist between tasks?

If your tasks are independent and CPU-bound, then running one per-CPU core is probably best - but in python you'll need multiple processes to take advantage.

Answer (score 3):

Rule of thumb: if a thread is going to do input/output, it may be worth separating it.

If it's doing number-crunching then optimum number of threads is number of CPUs.

Answer (score 0):

Testing will tell you.

Basicly try, and benchmark.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general answer for this ... yet. But there is a trend. Since computers get more and more CPU cores (try to buy a new single CPU PC ...), using threads becomes the de-facto standard.

So if you have some work which can be parallelized, then by all means use the threading module and create a pool of workers. That won't make your code much slower in the worst case (just one thread) but it can make it much faster if a user has a more powerful PC.

In the worst case, your program will complete less than 100ms later -> people won't notice the slowdown but they will notice the speedup with 8 cores.